# How to deal with timestamps given to example time-travel related questions?

Tags: discussion

[How do you prove you're from the future?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12348/how-do-you-prove-youre-from-the-future) gives an example of somebody coming back from 2100.  What will happen if this site still exists 100 years from now?

Would it make sense to limit using example years in some way, or is this problem not important, in this example, for another 85 years anyway?

What if the example had used 2020?

Comment: Welcome to meta and thanks for bringing your question here!

Comment: I guess we'll need to close the question before that moment.

Answer (score 4):

I think people will figure it out from context. The timestamp of the post is visible, after all.  If you come across a discussion about planning for the Y2K problem, does that confuse you?  I doubt it, because you know the context.

Failing that, if it causes problems, people will just edit those posts at the time.

I don't think we need rules about this.  Even for a question that uses 2020.

Comment: The Y2K problem will always be the Y2K problem - a set date in existence;  The future is a time relative to now, "now changes."